# Half secant in Circle

Tags: geometry

OT and OQP are tangent and secant respectively drawn from external point $O$ of a circle centered at $C$. Mid-point M of the secant is joined to center $C$,an arc is drawn with center $O$ to be tangential at $M$ cutting normal $TC$ at $X$.

Show that $TX= QM.$

[image: Circle Half Secant]

Comment: The above helps to further recognize  composition of each factor  $ OP,OQ $ of $ OT^2$ as a quadratic equation root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$TX^2 = OX^2-OT^2 =OM^2-OT^2 = (OQ+QM)(OP-QM)-OT^2$$
but since $OP\cdot OQ = OT^2$,
$$ TX^2 = QM(OP-OQ)-QM^2 = 2 QM^2-QM^2 = QM^2 $$
as wanted.